# Python, List to Json

Tags: python, json

Afternoon Folks.

I am trying to get all the items in a list converted to Json and saved to a file, with python i've read that I would need to get each item as `item.__dict__` which gives me the desired output on the python shell, when saving it to file and validating the json afterwards its not correct.

So what I would like to find out is what the best way would be to convert items in a list to json

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list1 = []


class BountyItem:
    def __init__(self, heading, price, tickets):
        self.heading = heading
        self.price = price
        self.tickets = tickets


url = 'https://www.bountycompetitions.co.uk/live-competitions/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

result = soup.find_all(class_='product')

for item in result:
    item_heading = item.find('a', attrs={'class': 'product-item-heading'})
    item_price = item.find('span', attrs={'class': 'woocommerce-Price-amount amount'})
    item_tickets = item.find('span', attrs={'class': 'status'})

    b_item = BountyItem(item_heading.text, item_price.text[1:], item_tickets.text)

    list1.append(BountyItem(b_item.heading, b_item.price, b_item.tickets))

for item in list1:
    with open("/home/pr0xibus/Documents/test.txt", 'a') as file:
        json.dump(item.__dict__, file)
```

Output of the json looks like

```
{
    "heading": "Highland Park \u2013 Valhalla Collection \u2013 Odin 16 year old Whisky",
    "price": "1.20",
    "tickets": "249 Left"
} {
    "heading": "Tom Ford Rose Prick Collection",
    "price": "0.99",
    "tickets": "189 Left"
} {
    "heading": "On The Go Giga Gaming Bundle",
    "price": "2.00",
    "tickets": "242 Left"
} {
    "heading": "Brand New 2020 KTM 450 SX-F",
    "price": "2.99",
    "tickets": "378 Left"
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to loop rather than `json.dump(list1, file)`? Also, you're creating two instances of the same BountyItem, which you could just make a dict directly rather than use a class if you just want JSON

Comment: If i use json.dump(list1, file) I get the error below

    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type BountyItem is not JSON serializable

Comment: Sure, do you need the class, though? If so, you could use `json.dump([item.__dict__ for item in list1] , file)`. The point is you want to dump a list, not append individual items

Comment: That gave me the a valid Json, thanks for that  ```json.dump([item.__dict__ for item in list1] , file)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump a list like so rather than appending individual objects

```
with open("/home/pr0xibus/Documents/test.txt", 'w') as file:
    json.dump([item.__dict__ for item in list1] , file)
```